# Prove that $\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} [1/n, 1 - 1/n] = (0, 1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an exercise for a set theory class. I already managed to prove $\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}] \subseteq (0, 1)$:

> Let $x \in \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$. Then, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N, n > 2$ such that $x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$. That is, $\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$.
>
> We also have $n > 0$, and thus $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{n}{n^2} > \frac{0}{n^2}$. Then $0 \lt \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.
>
> Since $\frac{1}{n} > 0$, $-\frac{1}{n} < 0$ and $1 - \frac{1}{n} \lt 1 - 0$.
>
> Putting all the inequalities together, $0 \lt \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} \lt 1$. This implies $0 \lt x \lt 1$. Therefore, $x \in (0, 1)$.

Though I don't know what to do about the other inclusion. I tried looking for a specific $n$ such that $x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$, but I can't really do that only knowing that $0 \lt x \lt 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $0 < x < 1$; by the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, there must exist an integer $N_1$ such that

$$0 < \frac 1 {N_1} < x$$

Likewise, since $1 - x > 0$, there is an integer $N_2$ for which

$$0 < \frac 1 {N_2} < 1 - x$$

Let $n = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, and try to show that $x \in [\frac 1 n, 1 - \frac 1 n]$.